# NSNotificationCenter doesn't send message in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications, corespotlight

I use Core Spotlight, and I use `UIPageController` as `RootViewController` and several `UIViewControllers`. Every controller has `UIView` I drawing a circle of information in there. When I slide between controllers and open new controller I sent `NSNotification` from current `UIViewController` to current UIView which is located on current `UIViewController`. I sent `NSNotification` that so turn on `NSTimer` in `UIView` for updating of information. It works is fine when I just open the app. My problem is when I find infromation from the app in spotlight search and open needed controller from spotlight search `NSNotification` doesn't sent. I tried several different methods and I cannot to find how I can to make it. Please tell me how can I make it?

**UPDATE** I also tried singleton pattern for `NSNotificationCenter` but it also didn't help me.

**UPDATE** I tried write Selector as `notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(turnOnMemoryTimer()), name: "turnOnMemoryArc", object: nil)`
     and it works when I launch app from spotlight search but it doesn't work when I just launch the app. For any help on this matter thanks!

I also tried to send notification from AppDelegate but it also didn't work

```
 switch startIndex {
        case 1:
            notificatioCenter.postNotificationName("turnOnCPUTimer", object: nil)
        default: break
        }
```

UIViewController

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    if GlobalTimer.sharedInstance.controllerTimer != nil {
        GlobalTimer.sharedInstance.controllerTimer.invalidate()
        GlobalTimer.sharedInstance.viewTimer.invalidate()
    }
    GlobalTimer.sharedInstance.controllerTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "showMemory", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // notifications

    notificationCenter.postNotificationName("turnOnMemoryArc", object: nil) // this message doesn't sent

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        notificationCenter.postNotificationName("checkMemoryOrientation", object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "changeMemoryOrientation", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }
}
```

UIView

```
// MARK: - var and let
    var arc = Arc()
    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    var boolForMemoryArc = false


       override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        if boolForMemoryArc == false {
            drawMemoryArc()
            boolForMemoryArc = true
        }
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "turnOnMemoryTimer", name: "turnOnMemoryArc", object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "changedMemoryOrientation", name: "checkMemoryOrientation", object: nil)
    }

    func turnOnMemoryTimer() {
        if GlobalTimer.sharedInstance.viewTimer != nil {
            GlobalTimer.sharedInstance.viewTimer.invalidate()
        }
        GlobalTimer.sharedInstance.viewTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "drawMemoryArc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the value of `notificationCenter` is not `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similiar issue and solved it like this:

```
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "turnOnMemoryTimer:", name: "turnOnMemoryArc", object: nil)
```

Receive AnyObject:

```
func turnOnMemoryTimer(notification: AnyObject) {

}
```

This needed change happened "spontaneous" the normal code was working for months.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer but it doesn't help me. I now tried it. How do you think because of what it happened?

Comment: I think it happened after the last Xcode update, but I am not sure.

Comment: Btw: did you try to Clean the project after the code change?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also reset Xcode yesterday. But it didn't help and I wrote this question.

Comment: I want to tell that when I change different method and I return to the first method         notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "turnOnMemoryTimer", name: "turnOnMemoryArc", object: nil). This method stopped work and I return to previous version of the project!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the NSNotification as parameter to the function you're calling. So, two tweeks:

```
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "turnOnMemoryTimer:", name: "turnOnMemoryArc", object: nil)
```

and

```
func turnOnMemoryTimer(notification: NSNotification) {
    // function body
}
```